# Предлог "в" словосочетании "в науке и практике"

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, орфоэпия

Корректен ли предлог `"в"` в сочетании: `"в науке и практике"`?

Answer (score 2):

Малоудачно сочетание «наука и практика»: наука включает в себя и практику, противопоставлять их едва ли корректно. Б.м., заменить его на, скажем, *теория и практика?*

Что до предлога, то он вполне уместен; что вас смущает?

**Обновление:** Я ни в коей мере не считаю такое словоупотребление ошибкой. Вот противопоставлять эти два понятия будет, как правило, ошибкой. А поскольку такая оппозиция имплицитно заключается в словосочетании *наука и практика* (где эти понятия мыслятся как одноуровневые), то его следует считать малоудачным и по возможности избегать во всех контекстах, где нежелательна терминологическая неопределённость.

Рекомендую быть осторожнее с поисковыми результатами Гугла как срезом практики письма. Любому лингвисту, занятому словарной работой, хорошо известно, что они как минимум требуют тщательной сортировки. На них можно взглянуть для удовлетворения собственного любопытства и получения первичной информации о частотности словоупотребления, но аргументировать ими свою позицию в большинстве случаев нельзя. А уж игра числами совсем несерьёзна.

Comment: Вы про то, нужен ли второй предлог "в" перед практикой: "в науке и *в* практике"?
Думаю, что не обязателен. Ваше употребление "в науке и практике" вплоне корректно.
Хотя хотелось бы контекст посмотреть.

"Наука и практика" - давно сложившееся сочетание
Результатов: примерно 4 490 000 (0,30 сек.)* 
©Google
Даже название журнала проскочило.


Comment: Не вижу даже намека на *противопоставление* ни в формулировке вопроса, ни в найденных гуглом результатах. Тем более не вижу причин говорить в данном контексте о какой-то терминологической неопределённости. При всем уважении.   

Гугл, конечно, не аргумент, когда идёт спор о нормативности, но сам факт огромного количества вхождений вполне показателен. Как ни крути, именно о сложившемся (пусть и ненормативном) словоупотреблении "игра с числами" даёт прекрасное представление.

Comment: С учетом всего сказанного я так и не понял, против чего конкретно вы возражаете. Почему автору стоит подумать над заменой "науки" на "теорию"?

Answer (score 0):

Я всё-таки восстановлю свой ответ автору именно как ответ. Ибо он содержателен по крайней мере в отношении конкретного вопроса о корректности предлога:

Вы про то, нужен ли второй предлог "в" перед практикой: "в науке и в практике"? Думаю, что не обязателен. Ваше употребление "в науке и практике" вполне корректно. Хотя хотелось бы контекст посмотреть.